# Question Mark "?" in apex code

Tags: apex

I was working on a controller, and came across a question mark in the code. What is this used for? I've searched for it but haven't found what it is used for.

```
if(dfield.isPermissionable()){
    string fieldAPIName = dfield.getName().endsWith('Id') && !dfield.isCustom() ? dfield.getName().removeEnd('Id') : dfield.getName();
    fieldList.add(fieldAPIName);
    fieldAPIToLabelMap.put(fieldAPIName,dfield.getLabel());
    selectedFields.add(fieldAPIName);
    tempList.add(dfield.getLabel() + ':' + fieldAPIName);
}
```

Comment: Check out this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142438/is-this-ternary-operator-logic-documented

Comment: Here you can see a bit about it: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called as ternary operator

`x ? y : z`

> Ternary operator (Right associative). This operator acts as a
>   short-hand for if-then-else statements. If x, a Boolean, is true, y is
>   the result. Otherwise z is the result. Note that x cannot be null.

```
dfield.isCustom() ? dfield.getName().removeEnd('Id') : dfield.getName();
```

The above statement means that is if `dfield.isCustom()` is `true` `dfield.getName().removeEnd('Id')` value will be returned `else` `dfield.getName()` value will be returned.

Comment: what does x,y and z refer in the comment? Make sure everything is explained with an example.

Comment: Now it looks fine

Comment: @Lokesh If you read the answer properly, I gave the exact example which the OP the has asked for where `dfield.isCustom()` is `x` which is `boolean`, if it evaluates to `true`, then `dfield.getName().removeEnd('Id')` i.e. `y` will be returned `else` `dfield.getName()` i.e. `z` will be assigned.

Answer (score 3):

Since Winter '21, the question mark is also used in Apex as a null-safe operator:

```
String myVal = a?.b // Evaluates to: a == null? Null : a.b
```

You may review the release notes (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm)